# Best way of opening a file (and ensuring file is chosen)

Tags: java, file-io

I have two seperate methods of opening a file.

The first uses a FileChoser with an additional file type filter.

```
JFileChooser inFileName = new JFileChooser();
 FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PCF & TXT Files", "pcf", "txt");

inFileName.setFileFilter(filter);
    Component parent = null;
int returnVal = inFileName.showOpenDialog(parent);`
```

The second uses a JOptionPane but has a loop to ensure the directory chosen exists

```
String filePath;
File directory;

do{
  filePath = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter directory");
   directory = new File(filePath);

    if (directory.exists()==false){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error with directory");
    }
 }while(directory.exists()==false);
```

I'm looking to get the best of both here. To be able to choose a file, using a file filter and also loop that function should that directory not be valid.

I've tried switching around variable names and the various functions in different places but I cant seem to get the loop (".exists" function) to work.

Comment: A `JFileChooser`'s purpose is for selecting files, so I would definitely choose the former.

Comment: But is it possible to create the desired loop?

Comment: Surely it's possible, but using a `JFileChooser` it would be impossible to choose a file that doesn't exist. (This is under the assumption that before accessing the selected `File`(s), you do a check to make sure the return value is equal to `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`)

Comment: Looking back on this question now it seems unnecessary. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your `JFileChooser` code to use a loop.

```
JFileChooser inFileName = new JFileChooser();

File file;
boolean valid = false;
while (!valid) {
  int returnVal = inFileName.showOpenDialog(null);
  if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    file = inFileName.getSelectedFile();
    valid = file.isDirectory();
  else {
    valid = returnVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION;
  }
}
```

Its worth mentioning that this kind of thing might be better achieved using;

```
jFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

Comment: Why would you do that? You could just invoke `setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY)` on your `JFileChooser` instance.

Comment: I'm pretty shure I can `$ mkdir mydir.txt`. `FileNameExtensionFilter` will return false to a file that is a directory.

Comment: @JeanWaghetti - just checked, `FileNameExtensionFilter` returns true for a directory regardless of name or extension.

Comment: Why you would use a `FileNameExtensionFilter` if you are only interested in choosing a directory?

Comment: Right, it will return TRUE if the file is a directory.